# How to initialize an object array with parameters？

Tags: c++

When I create a object whose constructor has parameter(s), how can I initialize it?
for example, if I write something like this:

```
object* array = new array[arraynumber];
```

if the constructor had no default parameters, the compiler would throw an error.
What can I do to deal with that problem?

Comment: Format code as code for better readabiliy. Also, use `std::vector` in place of arrays.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why you want to have constructors without parameters in your classes. Read about the [C++ rule of five (or 3 or 0)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your *array* using a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

**Quote:** http://en.cppreference.com

> std::vector is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays

```
struct object
{
    int i;
    std::string s;
    explicit object(int i, std::string const& s): i(i), s(s) {}
};


std::vector<object> array(arraynumber, object{4, "hello"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<object[]> fs(new object[6] {
    object(4), object(8), object(15), object(16), object(23), object(42)
});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ajbsJa).

but `std::vector` seems better.

Comment: Strange, clang rejects the code [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce2baaf1e86df50).